# curl hangs while uploading on Windows

Tags: bash, curl, hockeyapp

I am using curl on mac and other windows machines to upload my artifacts to HockeyApp service. On one of my machines that runs windows , "curl" constantly "hangs/freezes" during upload.

Here is the command :
curl -F notify=0 -F status=2 -F ipa=@app/build/outputs/apk/app-production-release-2.4.2-SNAPSHOTv42.apk -F dsym=@app/build/outputs/mapping/production/release/mapping.txt -H X-HockeyAppToken:[MY_TOKEN_HERE]https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/[MY_APP_REFERENCE]/app_versions/upload

On windows there is no curl by default , so I use the one installed with [this](http://git-scm.com/download/win) git distribution. I just add the path to curl to path environmental variable. This approach works well on 2 other windows machines. In fact when I open git-bash , the curl command also executes fine. But any attempt to run it from cmd.exe leads to "hanging/freezing".

Any idea on how can I troubleshoot/debug it ?

EDIT :
I have already tried other curl distributions for windows , same result...

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same issue of curl as well when trying to deploy my app from VSTS to Hockeyapp. in the end I've chosen for not using curl but just using plain powershell on Windows. it's a bit more complicated but it works the same way.

I've uploaded this script to GitHub and can be found there:
https://github.com/Geertvdc/UWPHockeyAppDeployScripts/blob/master/UploadUWPToHockeyApp.ps1

so instead of curl I use Invoke-RestMethod from powershell to do the same call to Hockeyapp.

Comment: Thanks .. definitely worth trying .. But why does it work on other windows machines , but not on this one ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your curl to the latest version

```
where curl
```

find out where current path of curl, using cywin cli

```
https://curl.haxx.se/windows/
```

Come here to find version you want update, download and give it a try.

Reason for this freezing is base on Windows config. I have laptop that need to ghost new installation of Windows 10. Before ghost, curl run well. After ghost, sometime it freezing.

I updated and it runs well now.

Also notice that when run

```
curl -s
```

curl will run in silent mode, that never hang out

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the "hang" sending an attachment with curl.

There were no problems posting a simple form. There were no errors or warnings when I tried to send the attachment, with `--verbose`: it just "hung".  Silent mode (`-s`) didn't help.

WORKAROUND:

```
$ where curl
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl.exe
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe
```

The "mingw64" version came with Git.  It was the default; it "hung".

I used the Windows version instead: it worked like a charm:

```
$ c:/windows/system32/curl --version
curl 8.0.1 (Windows) libcurl/8.0.1 Schannel WinIDN
Release-Date: 2023-03-20
```